# Magento: CONFIG_PATH_BACKEND_FRONTNAME is not defined

Tags: magento2.4.3

I have installed **Magneto 2.4.3 p1** after installing i have replaced my *app/code* and *app/design* with my previous projects *app/code* and *app/design* when i run setup:upgrade i get this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check your **env.php** file or in database **core_config_data table**

> app/etc/env.php

```
<?php
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
    'remote_storage' => [
        'driver' => 'file'
    ],
    'queue' => [
        'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1
    ],
    'crypt' => [
        'key' => '7cc0e0c57bf9f2922ab9d04805879b91'
    ],
    'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'magento245',
                'username' => 'magento',
                'password' => 'Admin@123',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1',
                'driver_options' => [
                    1014 => false
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],


    compare with your backend path
```

Comment: i checked all are same.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the app/etc directory?
Please check if the app/etc directory exists.
app/etc/config.php, env.php, di.xml, db_schema.xml, NonComposerComponentRegistration.php, registration_globlist.php, vender_path.php

Comment: Yes they exists.